# Mongoose - Query an array of objects, and return objects whose field match query params

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to get objects whose fields match the query parameters. Here's my document structure:

```
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("606cd605807c6b2b08fe064c"),
        "description" : "test",
        "shopname" : "MP Auto Parts",
        "state" : "Abia",
        "lga" : "Aba South",
        "address" : "3A Ekpereng street",
        "telnum" : "09137700528",
        "email" : "mp@gmail.com",
        "owner" : "605e8c09c7053d4248935dc4",
        "items" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("606cdae7de0b153c84bb1d21"),
                        "vehicletype" : "benz",
                        "model" : "c class",
                        "year" : "2020",
                        "part" : "piston",
                        "price" : 3000000,
                        "imageurl" : "https://res.cloudinary.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/image/upload/v1617746664/ghywaik0g1ze6rg6y0pw.jpg",
                        "imageid" : "ghywaik0g1ze6rg6y0pw",
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-04-06T22:04:23.906Z"),
                        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-04-06T22:04:23.906Z")
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("606cd6a7807c6b2b08fe064d"),
                        "vehicletype" : "honda",
                        "model" : "acura",
                        "year" : "2020",
                        "part" : "door",
                        "price" : 300000,
                        "imageurl" : "https://res.cloudinary.com/xxxxxxxxxx/image/upload/v1617745576/mstmrwo6kaxhfibngpew.jpg",
                        "imageid" : "mstmrwo6kaxhfibngpew",
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-04-06T21:46:15.274Z"),
                        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-04-06T21:46:15.274Z")
                }
        ],
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-04-06T21:43:33.499Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-04-06T22:04:23.907Z"),
        "__v" : 2
}
```

Here's my code with select fields option:

```
Shop.find({}, { vehicletype: vehicletype, model: model, year: year, part: part  } )
    .where({state: state, lga: city })
    .select('vehicletype model year part price imageurl') // Note select option
    .exec(function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.json(err);
        }
        console.log('results ', results)
   });
```

It returns only an array of document ids, like:

```
[
  { _id: 60715a7554b2d70b0c7f84f4 },
  { _id: 607230ef2e9af434a4543a76 }
]
```

I get close to what i want without the select option:

```
Shop.find({}, { vehicletype: vehicletype, model: model, year: year, part: part  } )
    .where({state: state, lga: city })
    .exec(function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.json(err);
        }
        console.log('results ', results)
   });
```

Which returns:

```
[
  {
    _id: 60715a7554b2d70b0c7f84f4,
    vehicletype: 'benz',
    model: 'c class',
    year: '2020',
    part: 'piston'
  },
  {
    _id: 607230ef2e9af434a4543a76,
    vehicletype: 'benz',
    model: 'c class',
    year: '2020',
    part: 'piston'
  }
]
```

The ids are those of the document, i want to get the document ids and the entire objects whose fields match my query.

Edit: What i really need in addition to the later code is to have the price and imageurl properties as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do :

```
Shop.find({ "items.vehicletype": vehicletype, "items.model": model, "items.year": year, "items.part": part, state: state, lga: city } )
    .exec(function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.json(err);
        }
        console.log('results ', results)
   });
```

Comment: That returns the document with items array of all the objects, would be nice if it had only the object whose fields are queried. 


` [
  {
    _id: 60715a7554b2d70b0c7f84f4,
    items: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    state: 'Akwa Ibom',
    lga: 'Uyo'
  },
  {
    _id: 607230ef2e9af434a4543a76,
    items: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    state: 'Akwa Ibom',
    lga: 'Uyo'
  }
]`

Comment: `Shop.find({ "items.vehicletype": vehicletype, "items.model": model, "items.year": year, "items.part": part, state: state, lga: city }, { "items.vehicletype": 1, "items.model": 1, "items.year": 1, "items.part": 1, state: 1, lga: 1 } )`

Comment: It returns a shop document, and its entire items array. My second code is close to what i want, it returns queried fields, i want to get the "price" and "imageurl" properties of that object as well.